# How do you retrieve photos from Titanium Cloud?

Tags: android, imageview, titanium, tableview, titanium-mobile

I'm a newbie in Titanium and web development. I uploaded some images to the Titanium Cloud Service (ACS) and wanna display them on my app.  Below is my code.  It runs, but I don't see any photos except for the title and back button.  Can someone take a look at my code and give me some hint on what I'm missing?  Thank you for your time!

```
    //Import the module
var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');
Cloud.debug = true;  // optional; if you add this line, set it to false for production 

// this sets the background color of the master UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups on it)
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

exports.getAlbumWin = function() {

    //create window
    var album_window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'#FFF',
        title: "Travel Diary"
    });

    //create title
    var title = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text: "All Trip Photos Submitted by Our Users",
        top:10,
        color: '#008000',
        textAlign: 'center',
        font: {fontSize:50}
    });


    var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        top: '5%',
        scrollable: true,
        width: '100%',
        minRowHeight: '500',
        bottom: '10%',
    });


    //Get diary entries, add them to the table view and display it  
    Cloud.Photos.query({
       page: 1,
       per_page: 10
    }, function(e) {
        var row, dateLabel, placeLabel, reviewLabel;
        var displayData = [];

        if (e.success){    
            alert('Count: '+e.photos.length);

            for (var i=0; i<e.photos.length; i++) {
                var photo = e.photos[i];

                var image2 = photo.urls.square.toImage();
                //create imageView
                var photoView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                    image: image2
                });
                //photo.urls.square

                displayData.push(photoView);
            }

            tableView.setData(displayData);
        } else {
            alert('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }   
    });

    //add a 'back' button
    var back_button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title: "Back",  
        height:160,
        left:40,
        right:40,
        bottom: '0%'    
    });     

    //Add Event Listener
    back_button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        //call an export function
        var win = require('home').getHomeWin;

        //create new instance
        var nextWin = new win();
        nextWin.open();
    });

    album_window.add(title);
    album_window.add(tableView);
    album_window.add(back_button);
    return album_window;
};
```

Comment: What are you getting in the "image2" ? Are you getting image Blob data in this variable ? Also try the solution Melvin has provided

Answer (score 0):

In appcelerator docs you can see what is image property of a Ti.UI.imageView,

> image : (String/Titanium.Blob/Titanium.Filesystem.File)
>   **Image to display**, defined using a local filesystem path, a File
>   object, **a remote URL**, or a Blob object containing image data. Blob and
>   File objects are not supported on Mobile Web.

So you could, use url as it is.

Try like this,

`var image2 = photo.urls.square_75;`

(Use as this unless you have specified a Custom Photo Size named square).

Look [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api/Photos-property-urls) for more information about "urls" property of Cloud photo object.